# How to generate Cucumber Report HTML locally

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I want to generate Cucumber HTML Report Locally, but not able to do so. I have followed lot of YT videos and blogs but they are using @CucumberOptions which is deprecated and also requires Runner. I am new with Cucumber, I followed Cucumber 10 min tutorial.

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.hertzbit</groupId>
<artifactId>third-party-test</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is RunCucumberTest File

```
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.*;
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.*;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("thirdpartytest")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

So far whichever blog post I went through none of them are talking about Cucumber 7. Also when I use cucumber.publish.enabled=true in src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties or src/test/resources/cucumber.properties, then also I am not able to push report to https://reports.cucumber.io, My preference is to create the reports locally.

Answer (score 4):

To generate report on local you can define `PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME`
like below

```
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, 
    value="junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml,
    json:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.json,
    html:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.html,
    timeline:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTimeline")
```

For `JUnit` use `junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml`
For `json` use `target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.json`
For `html` use `target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.html`
And For `timeline` use `target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTimeline`

And if you set cucumber.publish.enabled=true then and only then it will publish on https://reports.cucumber.io else it will stay on local only. it will be in your `target/cucumber-reports` directory